# Does data persist when navigating between frames in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I noticed that when logging out of my app, it takes me back to the login screen as intended. However, the input fields are still populated with previous login info (i.e. email/password). I thought they would be empty again upon navigating back to the login screen, but this isn't the case.

Here is my login.js file with respect to loading actions:

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

var home_navigation = {
    moduleName: "views/home/home",
    clearHistory: true
};

var page_data = new Observable({
    email: "",
    password: ""
})

exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = page_data;
}
```

There are other functions below this, but they just the email/pass and perform login logic as well as navigate to the appropriate screen, without storing the email/password anywhere locally. Also, there are no checks for previous session or anything like that.

Comment: you can use backstackVisible: false to prevent your users navigating back to the login page at all. See this ink: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#example-8--page-navigation-without-saving-navigation-history__

Answer (score 0):

When u leave its saved only in memory and its not available to other parts of app until saved somewhere like application-settings or db

Comment: When you say 'leave' do you mean navigate away from a frame? Concerning the part about it being saved in memory, does this mean any time I don't want previous input to display, I must clear out the observable before navigating away?

Comment: If for example someone can logout and relog back either clear it before navigating to other pages(i have done this) or clear it when page loads